# Run specific class function using cron in magento 2

Tags: magento2, crontab

We can run model/observer function using cron as below in magento 1:

```
<crontab>
     <jobs>
         <CronCheck>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/15 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>khaosconnect/Observer::checkCronJobs</model>
            </run>
         </CronCheck>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

so `checkCronJobs` function executed according to scheduled cron job.

In magento2 how we can run the specific class function using cron?
As we have use below in magento 2 :

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Cron;
class Runcronjobs
{
   protected $_logger;
   public function __construct(
       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
   ) 
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

   public function execute()
   {
       //Edit it according to your requirement
       $this->_logger->debug('Cron run successfully');
       return $this;
   }
}
```

In magento 2 I have `checkCronJobs` function in `namespace Company\Module\Model` class;

Is there any other way to call function in cron or we need to pass `checkCronJobs` with all dependencies in `Runcronjobs.php` file as we do normally in M2.

Comment: what your actual requirement to execute other function or another class in observer, you can directly write code here according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can add dependency of your model to cron class

```
namespace Company\Module\Cron;
class Runcronjobs
{
   protected $_logger;
   protected $_checkCron;
   public function __construct(
       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
       Company\Module\Model $checkCron
   ) 
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_checkCron = $checkCron;
    }

   public function execute()
   {
       //Edit it according to your requirement
       $this->_checkCron->checkCronJobs();
       $this->_logger->debug('Cron run successfully');
       return $this;
   }
}
```

It will help you i think , please try once .